# JMX Thread stuck on ClientNotifForwarder

Tags: java, multithreading, jmx

Our application connects to several jmx agents (about 50) to poll jmx data in frequent interval. After some time (about a day) application becomes irresponsive. We looked at thread dump and seeing large number of threads stuck on ClientNotifForwarder..

Eg:

```
"ClientNotifForwarder-50" daemon prio=3 tid=0x09aa3800 nid=0x330 runnable [0xd3a90000..0xd3a90c70]
java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:129)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:218)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:237)
    - locked <0xe2538af0> (a java.io.BufferedInputStream)
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readByte(DataInputStream.java:248)
    at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.executeCall(StreamRemoteCall.java:195)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(UnicastRef.java:142)
    at com.sun.jmx.remote.internal.PRef.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl_Stub.fetchNotifications(Unknown Source)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector$RMINotifClient.fetchNotifs(RMIConnector.java:1291)
    at com.sun.jmx.remote.internal.ClientNotifForwarder$NotifFetcher.fetchNotifs(ClientNotifForwarder.java:503)
    at com.sun.jmx.remote.internal.ClientNotifForwarder$NotifFetcher.run(ClientNotifForwarder.java:395)
    at com.sun.jmx.remote.internal.ClientNotifForwarder$LinearExecutor$1.run(ClientNotifForwarder.java:83)
```

Any help in identifying root cause is appreciated...

Thanks,
Raja

Comment: We're seeing a similar problem. Our stack trace is a little different, but I think the root cause may be the same.

Comment: May be associated with this bug which has been marked as "10-Fix Delivered": http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6199899

Answer (score 0):

Try setting connect and read timeout properties from command line.

```
sun.net.client.defaultConnectTimeout
sun.net.client.defaultReadTimeout
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/net/properties.html

Assuming you have sufficient retrial mechanism in place.